# Windows Sleep is Fake (YouTube plays for hours while "Sleeping")

Tags: windows-10, sleep, shutdown, power-management, youtube

I have a habit of turning off my computer (sleep not shutdown) while I'm watching youtube. When I do this the computer pretends to sleep by turning off the screen, and even the hard-drive and "thinking" lights turn off. I then go to sleep for  hours while the computer sleeps too. Then I wake up and turn my computer back on. Here is what I find:

1. the computer mouse is often still hovering over the "sleep button" with the windows start menu up (as if it never vanished when clicked).
2. You tube continues to play silently for hours.

Today I found I'd been watching hours of political videos when I was sleeping and my computer screen and sounds were off because they were in "sleep" mode. WHAT THE HECK IS GOING ON? Why does sleep not mean sleep? Why does YouTube play 3 other videos when the computer is not supposed to by using it's computing power?

Comment: In Advanced Power Settings, turn Hybrid Sleep OFF. Check also for Modern Sleep if you have it and turn that OFF as well. Restart and Suspend again. It should be now properly suspended

Comment: "Allow hybrid sleep" already shows it was set to "off". I do not see Modern Sleep listed as an option. Any other ideas?

Comment: Perhaps (a) update the Power Driver and / or (b) remember to turn off You Tube before suspending.

Comment: Is the power LED pulsing when it "sleeps"?

Answer (score 1):

Sourced from Answers:Microsoft - [Windows 10 won't go to sleep after recent fall update](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-power/desktop-computer-wont-go-to-sleep-after-recent/1353c298-0fc5-47ac-a803-a96102c78a4e)

> Run an admin command prompt
>       `powercfg -requests`   This command lists all processes or services currently running that are preventing the computer from
>   sleeping.

Though really it would be expected that any 'media player' - YouTube, online radio station, online game etc, would be preventing sleep, as a matter of course.